# Easier IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I just wrote this and was thinking there must be an easier/more clean way to do this as it looks terrible doing it this way:

```
if(isset($_GET['m']) && isset($_GET['v'])) {
    Router::Get($_GET['m'], $_GET['v']);
} elseif(isset($_GET['m'])) {
    Router::Get($_GET['m'], "");
} else {
    Router::Get("", "");
}
```

I'm looking for a cleaner way, like:

```
Router::Get(is('m'), is('v'));
```

Any suggestions to shorten/clean this kind of if-statements?

Comment: What you are looking for is something called a ternary operator.The following link has some great uses of ternary operators. `http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators`

Comment: Unrelated: If you pass multiple arguments to `isset()`, it will return `TRUE` if *all* of them are set.

Comment: Router::Get(isset($_GET['m']) ? $_GET['m'] : "",isset($_GET['v']) ? $_GET['v'] : "");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encapsulate the logic:

```
Router::$query = $_GET;
Router::Get('m', Router::Get('v'))

class Router {
    static public $query;
    static function Get($name, $default = '') {
        return isset(self::$query[$name]) ? self::$query[$name] : $default;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for, clean and easy solution! Thanks Meze for this awesome input.

Answer (score 7):

Can do,

```
$m = isset($_GET['m']) ? $_GET['m'] : "";
$v = isset($_GET['v']) ? $_GET['v'] : "";
Router::Get($m, $v);
```

Comment: This is probably as clean as it could get. +1

Comment: I was indeed thinking about the same, but no solution to do it inside the `Router::Get()` function?

Comment: @JoranDenHouting you can inline the `isset` checks but that wont make it cleaner. Since you're dealing with raw input here your first order of business should be to check your input. It's ok if that takes up some lines.

Comment: Router::Get(isset($_GET['m']) ? $_GET['m'] : "", isset($_GET['v']) ? $_GET['v'] : "");

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I know but it wouldn't make things cleaner indeed. What about a custom function for a check? To make `is()` check and return the value or an empty string?

Comment: @RafaelBarros: That's a variable variable (and a typo, I guess). You're probably seeing an old version of the answer. It's already been fixed!